# Errors with .Any and .Contains for Linq query for Oracle

Tags: linq

I am trying to create the following code in LINQ. I am using Linqpad to test my code but keep getting the error:

> "NotSupportedException: Constructing or initializing instances of the type <>f__AnonymousType0`2[LINQPad.User.RNIS_MAINTBOUNDARY_V,System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int32]] with the expression http://localhost:14722/WCFDataservice.svc/RNIS_DRE_AREA_V is not supported."

My code is as below:

```
var roads =
from d in RNIS_MAINTBOUNDARY_V
let ts2 =    
            from dretab in RNIS_DRE_AREA_V
            select dretab.DRE_CODE 
        where ts2.Contains(d.AUTH_ID)
    select d;
    roads.Dump();
```

For reference, the 2 fields for the join, namely auth_id and dre_code are both Oracle number fields. Why do I get this error?

Answer (score 0):

Your LINQ query gets translated into the chain of method calls

```
var roads = RNIS_MAINTBOUNDARY_V
    .Select(d => new { d, ts2 = RNIS_DRE_AREA_V.Select(dretab => dretab.DRE_CODE) })
    .Where(τ0 => τ0.ts2.Contains(τ0.d.AUTH_ID))
    .Select(τ0 => τ0.d);
```

any by the exception it looks like LINQ to Entities doesn't like the `{ d, ts2 = ... }` anonymous type.

Try just moving the inner query into the lambda:

```
var roads = RNIS_MAINTBOUNDARY_V
    .Where(d => RNIS_DRE_AREA_V.Select(dretab => dretab.DRE_CODE).Contains(d.AUTH_ID));
```

LINQ to Entities might not like *this* either, so you could try a real join:

```
var roads = RNIS_MAINTBOUNDARY_V
    .GroupJoin(
        RNIS_DRE_AREA_V,
        d => d.AUTH_ID,
        dretab => dretab.DRE_CODE
        (d, dretabs) => new { d, count = dretabs.Count() })
    .Where(p => p.count > 0)
    .Select(p => p.d);
```